# Get years and month between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying this code:

```
$start_date = "2015-08-19";
$end_date = "2016-02-19";
$begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
$end = new DateTime( $end_date);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1Y'); // 1 Year interval

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
foreach ( $period as $dt ){
    echo $dt->format( "Y" );
}
$intervals = new DateInterval('P1M'); // 1 month interval

$periods = new DatePeriod($begin, $intervals, $end);
foreach ( $periods as $dts ){
    echo $dts->format( "m" );
}
```

I'm getting output like this:

```
year:2015
Month:08,09,...,01
```

In this output I'm not getting year:2016 and month:02. I want my output like this:

```
year:2015,2016
Month:08,09,...,01,02
```

How can I get this?

And if my end date is "2016-08-20"

than i m getting year:2016 but not getting  month :08

Note that my start date and end date is not fixed.

Comment: If you realise you don't get the February 2016. Since you look at the intervals you don't get 2016. You can add +1 to the month and year ?

Comment: so how can i get that

Comment: take a look: https://vasavaa.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/date-difference-or-count-day-or-month-or-year-between-two-dates-in-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, the end date is not included

You may also modify the end date like that

```
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day +1 year' );
```

See php's DateTime [modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) for more info.

**Update**

If end year is more than 1 year bigger than the begin date then adding a year will indeed return a year more than what we want.

A solution is to check and add the year only if is needed like that:

```
if($begin > (new DateTime( $end_date))->modify('-1 year')) {
    $end->modify( '+1 year' );  
}
$end->modify('+1 day');
```

Comment: if my end date is 2016-10-19 than i m getting 2017 also i need only year and month between two date so its not wrking

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to achieve this:

```
<?php
$start    = (new DateTime('2015-12-02'))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime('2016-05-06'))->modify('first day of this month');

//For Year
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 year');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
echo 'Year: ';

foreach ($period as $dt) 
{
    echo $dt->format("Y") . ",";
}

//For Month
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
echo '<br/>Month: ';

foreach ($period as $dt) 
{
    echo $dt->format("m") . ",";
}
?>
```

> Alternatively, you can display it nicely in `Y-m` format by the following code:

```
$start    = (new DateTime('2015-12-02'))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime('2016-05-06'))->modify('first day of this month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) 
{
    echo $dt->format("Y-m") . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: I need  to display in dropdown in two diff dropdown one for year and second for month

Comment: In that case the first solution would be great. Let me write a code for the dropdown menu as well. Will take a couple of minutes!

Comment: No its also not wrkng bcz  
if my end date is 2016-10-19 than i m getting 2017 also i need only year and month between two date

Comment: I added the `modify` to `the first of the month` to the code. I checked it and it's working for me. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

since the year 2016 and the month 02 is not completed you are not getting it.
try this

```
$start_date = "2015-08-19";
$end_date = "2016-02-19";
$begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
$end = new DateTime( $end_date);
$end->add(new DateInterval('P1Y1M'));
$interval = new DateInterval('P1Y'); // 1 Year interval

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
foreach ( $period as $dt ){
    echo $dt->format( "Y" );
}
$intervals = new DateInterval('P1M'); // 1 month interval

$periods = new DatePeriod($begin, $intervals, $end);
foreach ( $periods as $dts ){
    echo $dts->format( "m" );
}
```

Comment: if my end date is 2016-10-19 than i m getting 2017 also i need only year and month between two date so its not wrking